# Spring MVC + Hibernate : Can't update entity "id to load is required for loading"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

**What i have:**

Currently i am developing a small banking app using spring mvc and hibernate. After successful login, the user is redirected to a preview page, where he can see all the different options for deposit/withdraw/view transactions, etc..

**What my problem is:**

After entering the number for deposit and clicking submit, it crashes with the message in the title.

**What i believe is causing the problem:**

I think it is something to do with the @Id Annotation on the entity class and that i am using a String(varchar) as primary key, although i am not really sure. Any help will be well received, adding my code down below.

```
package nselect.BankingApp.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import nselect.BankingApp.entities.Users;
import nselect.BankingApp.services.UsersService;

/**
 * Controller for the inner part of the app, meaning after the user logins
 * 
 * @author Asus
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MainController {
    
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview")
    public String getMainView(Model model, @ModelAttribute ("user") Users user) {
        
        double currentBalance = user.getAccBalance();
        model.addAttribute("balance", currentBalance);
        
        return "preview";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview/deposit")
    public String returnDepositForm() {
        
        return "depositForm";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview/deposit/depositConfirmation")
    public String deposit(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute ("user") Users user) {
        
        Users currentUser = usersService.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        
        double deposit_amount = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("deposit_amount"));
        
        currentUser.setAccBalance(deposit_amount);
        usersService.update(currentUser);

        return "deposit_confirmation";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview/withdraw")
    public String withdraw() {
        
        return null;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview/viewTransactions")
    public String viewTransactions() {
        
        return null;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/preview/transfer")
    public String transfer() {
        
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Entity class:

```
package nselect.BankingApp.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


/**
 * Entity class for all the users in the app
 * @author Asus
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {
    
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="acc_balance")
    private double accBalance;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Users() {
        
    }
    

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
        

    public double getAccBalance() {
        return accBalance;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setAccBalance(double accBalance) {
        this.accBalance = accBalance;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", accBalance=" + accBalance + ", email="
                + email + "]";
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
package nselect.BankingApp.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import nselect.BankingApp.dao.GenericDao;
import nselect.BankingApp.dao.UsersDao;
import nselect.BankingApp.entities.Users;

@Service
public class UsersService implements GenericDao<Users> {
    
    private UsersDao usersDao;
    
    public UsersService() {
        
        this.usersDao = new UsersDao();
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Users entity) {
        usersDao.openCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        usersDao.persist(entity);
        usersDao.closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Users entity) {
        usersDao.openCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        usersDao.update(entity);
        usersDao.closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Not being used, just a implementation of the interface method
     */
    @Override
    public Users findByID(int id) {
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public Users findByUsername(String username) {
        
        usersDao.openCurrentSession();
        Users user = usersDao.findByUsername(username);
        usersDao.closeCurrentSession();
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Users entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> findAll() {
        
        usersDao.openCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        List<Users> users = usersDao.findAll();
        usersDao.closeCurrentSessionWithTransaction();
        
        return users;
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
package nselect.BankingApp.dao;

import java.util.List;

import nselect.BankingApp.entities.Users;

public class UsersDao extends SessionTransactionControl implements GenericDao<Users> {

    @Override
    public void persist(Users entity) {
        super.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Users entity) {
        super.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        
    }

    @Override
    public Users findByID(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
    public Users findByUsername(String username) {
        
        Users user = super.currentSession.find(Users.class, username);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Users entity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> findAll() {
        
        List<Users> users = super.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Users u").getResultList();
        return users;
    }



}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Deposit money</title>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
        <form action="deposit/depositConfirmation">
        
            Amount you want to deposit: <input type="text" name="deposit_amount">
            <input type="submit" value="Deposit">
        
        </form>
        

        </body>
    </html>
```

MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `username` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `acc_balance` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

From Tomcat:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/BankingApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2773)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2713)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3312)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3274)
    at nselect.BankingApp.dao.UsersDao.findByUsername(UsersDao.java:29)
    at nselect.BankingApp.services.UsersService.findByUsername(UsersService.java:49)
    at nselect.BankingApp.controller.MainController.deposit(MainController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please provide error stack trace?

Comment: Also I noticed that you initialize dao like this `this.usersDao = new UsersDao();`. Are you sure that all data like datasource and session factory, transaction management will be properly initialized

Comment: Hi, added the console log from tomcat. As for the initialization - i can provide link to github repo, its public.

Comment: this is the github repo : https://github.com/NakoNachev/BankingApp, in case you are interested in, so that i don't spam the main comment.

Comment: The error is quite clear. You aren't submitting a `username` to the `deposit` method, no `username` (it is `null` probably) and thus this error. Next tot hat your code is flawed as well (it will not work with multiple concurrent requests and doesn't leverage best practices/good practices).

Comment: Spring does lots of useful work for you. Avoid injecting `HttpServletR*`; instead, you can simply say `@RequestParam("deposit_amount") Double depositAmount`.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean by i am not submitting a username. Normally after login i save the user as a modelAttribute and i am calling it to update the deposit value. chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic Thanks for the suggestion,I somehow missed it.

Comment: Nvm, understood the error, thanks for the answers!

Comment: Your form for the amount doesn't contain the username, hence it isn't part of the request, hence the `User.username` is empty. Which leads to the error.

Comment: Still i am not making it clear, probably due to my lack of knowledge on the subject. I don't want my form to contain the username or have a field for it. I pass the username and password to a User object upon login via my other controller. I do it that way, so that the user doesn't have to manually type it everytime, but rather  have the data saved in the session. I think the problem may lie in the transfer of data between controllers, therefore making the object null and not being able to identify it for hibernate. Thank you once again for the time spent explaining to me.